# probability of hitting a position on a dart board

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm working through some problems in Larson's "Introduction to Probability Theory and Statistical Inference". My vector calculus is very rusty right now, so I'm having some issues with some of the problems dealing with vector random variables. I was hoping to get some assistance with the following problem:

> Assume the density for the impact point $(X_1,X_2)$ on the dartboard is constant (equals $a$, say) for $(X_1,X_2)$ in the bull's-eye $(x_1^2 + x_2^2 \le 1)$ and for all other $(x_1,x_2)$ on the target the density decreases linearly with the radius $r = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$ and equals zero for $r\ge10$ (density equals $c-br$). Thus $f_{X_1X_2}(x_1,x_2)$ has a flat top and decreases for $x_1^2+x_2^2>1$. Derive the density function if there is probability $\frac{1}{2}$ of hitting the bull's eye

so the first part is pretty trivial, so I've solved that ;). i.e., for the bull's eye:

$f_{X_1X_2}(x_1,x_2) = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1c\:r\:dr\ d\theta = c*\pi$

and since there is probability $\frac{1}{2}$ of hitting the bull's-eye: $\;\;c = \frac{1}{2\pi} \;\;\;$ for $\;\;0<x_1^2+x_2^2<1$

Now, the next part is where I'm getting lost. I first tried to solve this by solving the integral:

$\int_{r=1}^{r=10}\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}\: (c-br)r\ dr\ d\theta = \frac{1}{2}\;\;\;$ where $c = \frac{1}{2\pi}$

however, that gives me the incorrect answer. I also tried to solve by computing the area of the partial cone swept out by line $c-br$, but that also led me in the wrong direction.

Apparently the correct answer to this problem is

$\;\;f_{X_1X_2}(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{64.8\pi}-\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}{648\pi}$ for $\;\;\; 1<x_1^2+x_2^2<100$

if anyone could help point me in the right direction, I would be really grateful!

Comment: Is it supposed to be $r\ge 100$ or $r\ge 10$ in the problem statement? You appear to be using the latter, which is also consistent with the answer you quote at the end.

Comment: It's r=10, not 100 (r^2=100). I fixed it. Good catch, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re on the right track. You’re given that the density outside of the bullseye depends only on the distance $r$ from the center. The linearity condition means that it will be of the form $k(10-r)$. Integrating over the annulus yields the equation $$P(1\le r\le 10) = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^{10}k(10-r)\,r\,dr\,d\theta = \frac12.
$$ Solve for $k$.

There might be a discontinuity in this density at $r=1$, which could be what led you astray.